# Can I access the keyboard in a virtual environment that was not created with sudo?

Tags: keyboard, sudo

I have a script which uses the arrows on the keyboard to provide user input.
The script required the keyboard package to be installed with pip install keyboard.

The script works fine outside the virtual environment if I run it with sudo.

I would like to be able to run that script inside the virtual environment without giving root access to that environment.

Is there a way to allow the virtual env to use the keyboard without giving it root privileges?

PS my keyboard is connected to the Pi via bluetooth, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Read this answer to see if it applies. [virtualenv without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348869/how-to-install-virtualenv-without-using-sudo)

Comment: you don't need to give full root access to something.  such measures are often handled by granting full access to something else that you then trust to take actions on behalf of users, limiting itself to only authorized actions.  the keenel has the ability to mess with hardware, but we trust it to a degree not to except in certain situations.  Key is figuring out exactly what permissions your script user needs, and limiting it to those.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) this is to be expected:

> To avoid depending on X, the Linux parts reads raw device files (/dev/input/input*) but this requires root.

Adding the user that runs the Python script to the relevant group should be enough. Depending on the OS, the group name will be `input`, `plugdev` or something similar. Check the ownership of `/dev/input/*` files to find out.